# Attribute selected option into a variable to show input field using SQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to attribute the selected value from my **dropdown** list into a **variable** that I can use in my sql query.

I know that I have to use Ajax or jQuery but I can't because I don't learn it yet

Picture 1 : [image]
Picture 2 : [image]

```html
<!-- Début PHP Catégories -->
<?php
 $resCat=mysqli_query($conne,$reqCat);
?>
         
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Catégorie</label>
  <div class="col-md-9">      
   <select class="form-control select" name="categorie" id="categorie" ">
   <?php
     while ($rowCat= mysqli_fetch_row($resCat)) {
   ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $rowCat[1] ?>"><?php echo $rowCat[0] ?></option>
      <?php
        } 
        $categorie = $_POST['categorie'];
      ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Fin PHP Catégories -->
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your case you can simply use a form and when you validate the button after having selected your option you just have to recover the value of the option and make your request

Comment: I can't because i have the whole forms in one form like you can see here http://i.imgur.com/EO4In3S.png